# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected (T_STRING) on line 1

Tags: php, parse-error

I am creating a script to prevent empty user Location field based on a previously developed filter function. On localhost everything works fine but online i got strangely his error :

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'QA_INCLUDE_DIR' (T_STRING) in /home/picas/public_html/plugin/location-required/profile-checker.php on line 1

below the code:

```
<?php

require_once QA_INCLUDE_DIR.'qa-filter-basic.php';

class qa_profile_checker {

    function filter_profile(&$profile, &$errors, $user, $oldprofile) {

        $fb = new qa_filter_basic();
        $userfields=qa_db_single_select(qa_db_userfields_selectspec());
        foreach ($profile as $key => $value) {
            // sanitize
            $profile[$key] = qa_html($value);
            foreach($userfields as $userfield) {
                if ($userfield['fieldid']==$key) break;
            }
            switch ($userfield['title']) {
            case 'location':    // Location (Required)
                $fb->validate_length($errors, $key, $value, 1, 100);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My local machine runs under windows and the server under Linux if that could help.

How comes that on localhost it's working fine but online it's not ?!

Comment: Where do you define `QA_INCLUDE_DIR`?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams It is not a problem of definition of `QA_INCLUDE_DIR`, if that value were simply undefined, it would guess at a value (likely ended in empty string). This is a parser error and occurs before evaluation of that constant occurs.

Comment: You can try two things, either do `require_once(QA_INCLUDE_DIR.'qa-filter-basic.php')` or `$path = QA_INCLUDE_DIR.'qa-filter-basic.php'; require_once $path)`

Comment: How and where do you define `QA_INCLUDE_DIR`? `

Comment: @MikeBrant: This is PHP. It would guess at `"QA_INCLUDE_DIR"` and emit a warning or notice. Except that warnings and/or notices are suppressed in the asker's configuration.

Comment: @MikeBrant First solution gives : 
`Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file in /home/picassau/public_html/qa-plugin/q2a-location-required/qa-profile-checker.php on line 1`


Second : `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$path' (T_VARIABLE) in /home/picassau/public_html/qa-plugin/q2a-location-required/qa-profile-checker.php on line 1`

@ManoloSalsas `QA_INCLUDE_DIR`is declared in the root